# Custom command to query for an element with role that does not exist

Tags: cypress

Using the following command:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getByRole', (role, options): Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>> => {
  return cy.get('[role]').filter((_, element) => {
    const roles = element.getAttribute('role').split(' ');
    return roles.includes(role);
  }, options);
});
```

Works fine if the element exists:

```js
cy.getByRole('alert').should('exist'); // works
```

But to check for an element which should *not* exist:

```js
cy.getByRole('alert').should('not.exist'); // fails
```

It will throw the error: `Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: [role], but never found it.`.

How can the function be adjusted to also allow for checking elements that you expect not to exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem. Maybe you are using an older version of Cypress? It used to be that the "assertion lookahead" feature could not look "through" callback code such as used in `.filter()`.

Here's my test to reproduce:

**The page fragment I used**

```html
<body>
  <div role="alert drowsy"></div>
</body>
```

**The test code**

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getByRole', (role, options) => {
  return cy.get('[role]').filter((_, element) => {
    const roles = element.getAttribute('role').split(' ');
    return roles.includes(role);
  }, options);
})

cy.visit('role.html')

cy.getByRole('alert').should('exist')

cy.getByRole('asleep').should('not.exist')
```

[image]

---

#### Missing role attributes

Of course, if there's not element on the page with `[role]` attribute your command will fail, but obviously if you are creating such a command for a page that uses roles there will be at least one role present.

If that's a wrong assumption, you can use a more general version that works even if there is no `[role]` attribute.

Note the use of optional chaining `element.getAttribute('role')?`, `roles?`

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getByRole', (role, options) => {
  return cy.get('*').filter((_, element) => {
    const roles = element.getAttribute('role')?.split(' ');
    return roles?.includes(role);
  }, options)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear response. It is indeed an element on the page that does not exist. A bit odd, I admin. But in my test I want to make sure that there is not an error message present :). I'll try the second suggestion.

Comment: I forgot to add `cy.get('*')` works for any tag - if you have consistent tags e.g `<span>` you can substitute `cy.get('span')`